# Is it possible to generate sound using light?

Tags: optics, acoustics

Someone recently claimed that ["flashing a light into a gas will generate a sound wave at the frequency of the flashing"](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/07/tiny-pillars-put-light-and-sound-in-a-quantum-superposition/). Is this true? If yes, what's the name of this effect? I guess it should be called optical acoustics or something?

I mean producing it directly, not by converting light into electricity/digital bits and then converting electricity/bits into sound, like the Theremin or the Laser harp.

By searching the internet for this I can only find about the opposite: generating light using sound: Sonoluminescence

Comment: https://www.photonics.com/Article.aspx?AID=36760   I hope I have got the effects the right way around:). **During the past decade, pioneering experiments using subpicosecond lasers demonstrated the generation and detection of acoustic and shock waves in materials with terahertz  frequencies. These very same experiments led to a new technique for probing the structure of semiconductor devices.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly true, however, I don't know the name of the effect in general. The most effective way to generate sound by absorption of light at the surface of a solid is through *laser ablation* (*i.e.* forced fracture / vaporization of matter which is then cast off the surface with attendant transfer of impulse into the medium), although one doesn't have to reach light levels needed to give rise to ablation for sound to be generated.

The most obvious way  to make sound is to focus a pulse of light with very high energy into an absorbing medium. The lit region's temperature rises very swiftly and then the expansion thus induced gives rise to an acoustic wave that propagates away from the small heated region. For a morbid and hideous example: this effect is somewhat like the generation of the blast wave by a nuclear weapon: the weapon's energy is mostly output as light (soft x-rays), which are wholly absorbed by the surrounding air within hunders of meters tup to a few kilometers (for the biggest weapons). The swiftly expanding, almost instantaneously heated air (the fireball) is what begets the blast (acoustic) wave.

I once worked on a project that sought to do acoustic tomography of steel blooms through the launching of sound from lasers focussed on the bloom's surface. One finds that the efficiency of this process is radically raised when ablation begins, although it is certainly detectable at much lower light levels.

A few-watt Q-switched Nd-Ya-G to produce microsecond pulses collimated to fill and focussed through a 0.3NA or higher objective onto the surface of most solids will give rise to a clearly hearable "tick" with each pulse; you can even ring a bell with the right pulse length.

Comment: I find it a bit strange that the scientists didn't find the time to think about giving a name to this effect. That makes me wonder how many such known phenomena exist that were not even given a name..